# How to insert space in the user defined variables in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I want to print the date as `2016-07-12 14:25:00`. I have been able to print this date, but not able to print the space there.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you share more details? Perhaps a screenshot. Is the date hard-coded in user defined variables or you are generating using some function ?

Comment: I have calculated the date using BeanShell. Also the date is generated as 2016-07-12%2014:25:00 if i mention the format as "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript function encodes space as %20, but it's shouldn't print it like that. Avoid using JavaScript when you can use Java.

To avoid problems stated in your question, try using Beanshell to generate it as you wish using something like:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String customDate = "2016-07-13 11:11:11"; // for hard-coded date
String currentDate = format.format(new Date()); // for current date

// Put those strings into JMeter variables for further use:

vars.put("customDate", customDate);
vars.put("currentDate", currentDate);
```

Comment: I am using the exact same code that you mentioned above, but i still get that %20 in the end result.

Comment: Where and how do you print date variable?

Comment: I have tried using the date variable in next sampler, printing it to console, to terminal, to text file and I haven't seen "%20" once. We are having very interesting situation... Are you encoding the parameters in some Request maybe?

Comment: Not encoding the parameters, but directly using them in the HTTP requests. I have the very same function as described above. And in my URI I am sending that variable ${currentDate} thats it. Not done anything other than the regular stuff. I am already going nuts on this one...

Comment: Are you using beanshell pre/post processor or sampler? Where did you put the code (function)? Can you please add HTTP request screenshot as well...